# In excel data is not coming in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when I click on excel sheet button selected employee data is not coming in excel sheet .
Controller Code -

```
   def advance_salary_xls 
    @employee_id = params[:employee_id]
    @advance_salaries = AdvanceSalary.where(id: @employee_id)
    @advance_salary_id.each do |e|
    @advance_salary = AdvanceSalary.find_by(id: e)
   end
    respond_to do |format|
    format.xls {render template: 'advance_salaries/advance_salary_xls.xls.erb'}
    end
  end
```

Comment: No need to take @employee_id as instance.

Comment: AdvanceSalary table will definitely have employee_id so that means you need fire the query on foreign key not the primary key.

Comment: @advance_salary_id, Where it is defined ?

Comment: Before going to write code, You should learn how to write the code with the technology.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written is wrong way to get the output. You need to take all the employees in the method and then you need to write the embedded code script on views to achieve the xls sheet.

```
def advance_salary_xls 
    @advance_salaries = AdvanceSalary.where(id: params[:employee_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xls {render template: 'advance_salaries/advance_salary_xls.xls.erb'}
    end
end
```